# Notepad++ cannot print

Tags: wine, printing, snap

I have installed notepad++ using Ubuntu Software Store. I tried printing, it does not work. I uninstalled notepad++, and installed it using `sudo snap install` method. Both methods bring up the following popup screen:

> Before you can perform printer-related tasks such as page setup or
>   printing a document, you need to install a printer.  Please install
>   one and retry.

My printer is Brother HL-2270 DW. I can print to my printer using other applications such as LibreOffice and Atom, yet, I cannot print using Notepad++. Anyone have a solution please? My Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7):

Open the software store, search for `notepad-plus-plus` and open the according page.

[image]

Click the `Permissions`-button and enable `Print documents`

Alternatively, for the folks who like the command-line:

```
snap connect notepad-plus-plus:cups-control
```