# Neither Gimp not Inkscape see my printer; working fine from other applications

Tags: printing, gimp, brother, inkscape

I just reinstalled this Ubuntu 19.10 from scratch. All is well, including the Brother MFC-J895DW multifunction printer. But when I start either Gimp or Inkscape, they don't see that any printer is installed!

[image]
[image]

Other applications have no problem using that device; both printing and scanning works fine.
[image]
[image]

**What can I do to fix this? Do some programs require additional stuff to be installed?**

***update:***

1. The commend by @mook765 was spot on. Why on earth is printing disabled by default??! Not available for Inkscape though, so that's still broken. I guess I will have to remove that and install it manually ... I don't know anything about snaps but it doesn't look to be all that great?
   [image] [image]
2. Following the ideas in the linked question, I tried `snap connect inkscape:cups-control` but it responded `error: snap "inkscape" has no plug named "cups-control"` so that's *also* not how to get Inkscape to print.
3. `lpstat -t` gives me the following (which doesn't tell *me* anything useful):

> `scheduler is running
>   system default destination: Brother_MFC_J895DW
>   device for Brother_MFC_J895DW: implicitclass://Brother_MFC_J895DW/
>   Brother_MFC_J895DW accepting requests since lør 11 apr 2020 00:00:04 CEST
>   printer Brother_MFC_J895DW is idle.  enabled since lør 11 apr 2020 00:00:04 CEST`

Comment: Are the applications installed as snaps? Check with `snap list`. If so, you may need to configure permissions for each snap. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168243/590937) shows an example how to do that with gnome-software.

Comment: what does `lpstat -t` tell you? What libraries are used by the applications to access the "list of printers", and do they use different lists?

Comment: @mook765 you are spot on! Put it as an answer?

Comment: You can install Inkscape from official repositories with `sudo apt install inkscape` (version is 0.92.3-1). The snap is slightly newer with version  0.92.4. I suggest you split your question into question and answer since you got some screenshots already.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. I opened software ( in Xubuntu should be similar in ubuntu)Clicked on Installed. Found Gimp, clicked to open. Clicked on permissions and moved tag to print. Same for inkscape.