# How can I print from the snap packaged version of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, snap

I'm running the latest stable version of snap packaged Firefox (78.0.2) on Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm unable to print to my Brother DCP-L2500D Laser printer - I can see and select the printer, but when I attempt to print a document I get a "Printing Failed" dialogue.

I assume this is related to permissions and how snap packages are isolated from the rest of the system.

I can print successfully from Chrome browser which is installed via apt.

Comment: [Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168230/590937)

Comment: I tried: sudo snap connect firefox:cups-control, still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here after moving from Firefox 8x to 91.3 ESR (snap) lately. Solved the problem by following this Mozilla help:

Reset Firefox printer settings: [`http://mzl.la/1BAQqop`](http://mzl.la/1BAQqop)

- Click on the “hamburger menu” button. (Alternatively, open `about:support`.)
- Click on “Help” and select “More Troubleshooting Information”.
- On the Troubleshooting Information page, go down to “Printing section”.
- Click on “Clear saved print settings”.

This will remove all modified (incompatible) print settings in Firefox (most likely inherited trough the former profile settings).

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

I was having trouble printing, too, but [the other answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1375434/308825) didn't work for me. I did notice a comment suggesting [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168230/590937).

Unfortunately the command line

```
sudo snap connect firefox:cups-control
```

did not immediately help me, either.

HOWEVER I was able to successfully activate printing using this procedure:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center application.
2. Search for Firefox and choose it (note it says "Installed" next to it).
3. Click the Permissions button.
4. Confirm that its Printing permission is set to ":cups-control".

On my system, Printing had been set to "(disconnected)." After I changed it to ":cups-control" my printers were visible in the Print dialog in Firefox.

UPDATE: In recent versions of Ubuntu (22.04 "Jammy" or later?), you can also change the application settings using the GNOME Settings menu. On my system, the "Print documents" permission is set to "core:cups-control" in Settings --> Applications --> Firefox Web Browser