# Unable to print from Gwenview

Tags: gwenview

I have installed Gwenview 20.04.0 from snap on Ubuntu 20.04.

When printing, the only option is print to file, PDF.

Is there any way to configure Gwenview to print to the system printer?

Also, the default paper size is A4. Is there any way to change the default to 'letter'?

A web search has so far failed to uncover any answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment by @mook765 I can improve/correct my original answer.

When installed as a snap package in Ubuntu gnome, Gwenview cannot be configured to print, except as a PDF.

To install Gwenview with printing capability one should install it from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gwenview
```

Then all the supporting packages will be installed which give Gwenview its full complement of abilities, including printing.

Comment: I don't think that this is correct, you installed gwenview as a snap, so you need to configure the permissions for the snap, take a look at [this example](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168230/590937) how to do so.

Comment: @mook765 All the configuration options on the snap are checked. None pertain to printing. However, I will try deleting the snap and reinstalling using synaptic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @mook765. Installing Gwenview from the command line was the solution.