# Brave browser webcam not working

Tags: webcam, brave

Brave is a awesome browser just like chrome or more.
It gives me a great experience. but i can't use webcam in brave! like, google meet, and others.
i have given access manually, turned on the hangout plugin, and other settings.
but my webcam is perfect, worked with chrome, mozilla, opera etc.
i have checked all other option, which provided by brave support community.
so if anyone faced the issue and solved, then please provide me.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Is Brave installed as a snap? Check out with `snap list`. If it's a snap, look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168230/notepad-cannot-print/1168243#), it's for notepad++, but the principle is the same, at least the GUI-method should work.

Comment: yes, i downloaded it using snap. you are awesome. it works finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo snap connect brave:camera core:camera
```

Reference:

https://www.patrickweber.info/webcam-funktioniert-nicht-in-brave-browser-ubuntu/

Comment: thanks, mate, its works