# Printing from Brave browser

Tags: printing, settings, brave

Axel Lieber suggests 2021jan07 to solve printing under Brave browser: In /Settings/Applications (of Ubuntu, not the browser) there are two entries for the Brave browser, one of them for "Permissions and access". But I can't find /Settings/Applications in my XUBUNTU. Any alternative location to use ?

Comment: Most likely you installed Brave as a snap. Check out with `snap list`. Look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168230/590937), it's for notepad++, but the GUI method in the answer should work for you if it is a snap.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the gui but you could use `snap connect brave:cups-control` .