# Irfanview "No printer installed or can't load printer" 18.04 Kubuntu

Tags: printing

I installed *Irfanview*. Works as expected. Only issue: I can't print.
Message on display "N*o printer installed or can't load printer*"

I have various work-arounds which I would like to avoid.

Printer is working as expected with other progs.

Kubuntu 18.04, updated on 2022-03-11; 64 bit; printer *Brother MFC*

Update
(comments so far not helpful!)

Now on Kubuntu 20.04 - same problem

@HEKTO -
Everything I use with IV works smoothly except printing.

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in April 2018, and reached 'End of Life' for its 3 years of flavour support on 1st May 2021 Therefore not supported on this site.

Comment: @David: According to Thomas Ward, Ubuntu flavors remain on-topic on Ask-Ubuntu just as long as vanilla Ubuntu: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19616/how-long-do-we-support-ubuntu-flavors, until 202304.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Not how I read it. He says 20.04 this is 18.04 End of discussion.

Comment: @David: Ubuntu 18.04 is not yet EoSS, thus 18.04 flavors are still on-topic on AU, at least that is what TW says in my previous link: **Any flavor of Ubuntu outside of the flavor team's 'support' period is still supported by Ask Ubuntu until the overarching main Ubuntu release reaches EoSS or EoL (per the core "Ubuntu" version and not the flavors).**. see also: https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle .

Comment: The IrfanView is a Windows product. Did you install it with the Wine? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope. No solution found so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my issue is:-

```
snap connect <application>:cups-control
```

in my case:

```
snap connect irfanview:cups-control
```

problem solved thanks to
[Notepad++ cannot print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168230/notepad-cannot-print/1168243#1168243)